# What it means by "MEMORY_TARGET" in this Oracle database error?

Tags: sql, oracle, virtualbox

I'm trying to run an Oracle database memory-management exercise on the VirtualBox Oracle Developer-Days VM.  I want to make scenario where I change the memory based on the archive-log (to get a pseudo intelligent system )

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
```

I'm not sure if this info helps , but here's my `/dev/shm` memory :

[image]

Any tips appreciated, thanks

Comment: // *Cause: The MEMORY_TARGET parameter was not supported on this operating system or /dev/shm was not sized correctly on Linux.
// *Action: Refer to documentation for a list of supported operating systems. Or, size /dev/shm to be at least the SGA_MAX_SIZE on each Oracle instance running on the system.

Comment: @OldProgrammer -  Hmm, so when you say `size /dev/shm to be at least the SGA_MAX_SIZE on each Oracle instance running on the system` - how to do that ?

Comment: I'm running the VM on Windows , so you're saying I should try running on Linux instead ?

Comment: You need to change the Linux system (_inside_ the VM) and increase the size for `/dev/shm`. Use your favorite search engine and search for this error. There are plenty of answers on how to adjust this setting